# Is there a way to display multiple collections on a single page using Backbone.js and Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, collections

I am trying to develop a single page application using Rails 3 and backbone.js. Is there away to instantiate two different collections in a router? Or would I need two routers routing to the same route?(I don't think this is possible)

I have two collections and I don't see why this is so hard to figure out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can instantiate and fetch as many collections, models, or views you like in a single route.

```
  function showBooksAndCars() {
    var carsCollection = new App.collections.Cars();
    var booksCollection = new App.collections.Books();
    carsCollection.fetch();
    booksCollection.fetch();
    var carsView = new App.views.CarsView({collection: carsCollection}).render();
    var booksView = new App.views.BooksView({collection: booksCollection}).render();
    $('div.cars').replaceWith(carsView.el);
    $('div.books').replaceWith(booksView.el);
  }
```

Comment: I would like to see this application that's all about books and cars, it seems :)